# getElementByClassName to change input value

Tags: javascript, forms, input, getelementsbyclassname

I have an input tag that is being included by a javascript. The resulting input tag looks like this:

```
<input class="mylivechat_prechat_name_box mylivechat_prechat_box" type="text">
```

Is there any way that I can add a variable to the end of the value of the input tag?

I've tried using the javascript to set the form field:

```
var myClassName =  document.getElementsByClassName('mylivechat_prechat_name_box mylivechat_prechat_box');
i = myClassName.length;
myClassName[i].value = "TheseAreMyChanges";
```

However, I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined

Comment: Indexing of the returned collection starts from 0.

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to actually *achieve*? Its not entirely clear

Comment: Hi Jamiec, yes, trying to change the input value of a form - which is being included/generated by a previously loaded javascript. For some reasons I'm always getting the undefined error.

Comment: I'm clearly doing something wrong with the selector, but I'm putting in exactly what chrome is telling me the class name is :/

Comment: `i = myClassName.length - 1;` try this

Answer (score 0):

In your code `myClassName[i]` will be `undefined`, since `i` holds the length and maximum index value will be `length - 1`. And string can be append at the end by `+=` which results concatenated value.

```
var myClassName =  document.getElementsByClassName('mylivechat_prechat_name_box mylivechat_prechat_box');
myClassName[0].value += "TheseAreMyChanges";
```

If you want to update the last element then get element by index `length -1`

```
var myClassName =  document.getElementsByClassName('mylivechat_prechat_name_box mylivechat_prechat_box');
myClassName[myClassName.length - 1].value += "TheseAreMyChanges";
```

Answer (score 0):

Array's are zero based, so if you read the `length` and use that index it is one more than the highest element. Trying to read an element outside the bounds of the array will return `undefined` - so use `length-1`:

```
var myClassName =  document.getElementsByClassName('mylivechat_prechat_name_box mylivechat_prechat_box');
var i = myClassName.length;
myClassName[i-1].value = "TheseAreMyChanges";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `querySelector` :

```
document.querySelector('.mylivechat_prechat_name_box.mylivechat_prechat_box').value+='NEW';
```

Add `:last-child` in the end of the selector if you want to get the last element :

```
document.querySelector('.mylivechat_prechat_name_box.mylivechat_prechat_box:last-child');
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.mylivechat_prechat_name_box.mylivechat_prechat_box');
elem.value += ' NEW';
```

```html
<input class="mylivechat_prechat_name_box mylivechat_prechat_box" type="text" value='OLD'/>
```

Comment: What makes you think they wanted the *first* element when everything about the question indicates they wanted the *last*?